# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

HI ALL,

I got an error  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, I am not getting wat the problem is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     System.loadLibrary("pfcasyncmt");
  }
  catch(){
  }
}
```

ERROR-
xception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pfcasyncmt in java.library.path

Answer (score 4):

Java cannot find the dll library. You must set the `java.library.path` property to point to the dll you want to load, when starting your application.`

```
java -Djava.library.path="the directory which contains your dll" .........
```

Comment: Hi,
I have set the java.library.path to dll directory.
now i got another error.


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\jsdk1.4.2_ibm\jre\bin\pfcasyncmt.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2144)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2004)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:824)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:910)
 at Test.LatestTestProeVersion1.main(LatestTestProeVersion1.java:30)

Comment: That new error message means that the DLL does not contain the native method you are trying to call in with the name, format etc. that Java expects it to be.

Answer (score 0):

In windows OS,type command:"path" can get the java.libray.path real path.or System.getProperty("java.library.path"),put the dll in any path of that results.Hope i clear my answer.